# ORA-01019 error only as an administrator

Tags: windows, oracle

I'm having a strange problem.

I've installed the Oracle 10g client on a terminal server running Windows Server 2008R2.  When I try to connect to Oracle, using, say, Toad, I receive the error "ORA-01019 unable to allocate memory in the user side".  But this only happens if I'm logged in as an administrator.

If I connect as a normal user, I can connect without issue.  Also -- if a normal user is connected, I can then connect without a problem as an administrator.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Does running the terminal server client in console mode change anything? Try the following command:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe /console
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your ORACLE_HOME environment variable is not set when you're administrator.

Comment: Just tried setting ORACLE_HOME - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Oracle Support note (363448.1) about getting this error on Terminal Server when NOT using an administrator account. It may be there's been a change to the privileges granted for 2008R2. Log an Oracle issue and they'll probably be able to tell you what is needed.